# Ubuntu Windows Key and Left/Right

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, gnome

In Windows 7 you can use Win+Left/Right to shift and resize a window so it only takes up half of the screen. This is really useful for working on two windows at the same time. Is there any obvious way to set this up in Ubuntu (gnome)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also looking and finally found:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> (NumPad)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> (NumPad)

For more shortcuts check out:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way is:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right / Left</kbd>